# Using namespaces in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular, but the first thing I wanted to use was namespaces (as use them elsewhere)

I have read a number of posts regarding namespaces in Angular, and wanted to get an opinion on an approach I was going to perhaps take...

I was thinking of structuring very similar to what is suggested elswhere (ie have a main app.js, and then divide by features or "views".

For example, if I wanted to use a namespace such as *TestModule*, I would have each Feature/View and it's associated Controller in a separate js file...

eg such a file will look something like...

```js
var TestModule = TestModule || {};

TestModule.View1 = function () {

  // Private helpers
  function cellTemplate(cellElement, cellInfo) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    ......
    
  };

  function controller($scope) {   
    $scope.testText = "umm, hello";
    $scope.gridData = [
      { col1: 'data 1', col2: 'data 2' },
      { col1: 'data 3', col2: 'data 4' },
    ];

    $scope.cellTemplate = cellTemplate;
  }

  return {
    // Controller
    Controller: controller
  }
}
```

And then in the main app.js. have something like..

```js
"use strict";

var TestModule = TestModule || {};
var ngGridApp = angular.module("ngTestApp", ['dx']);
ngGridApp.controller("gridController1", TestModule.View1().Controller);
ngGridApp.controller("listController1", TestModule.View2().Controller);
```

etc

These are just my initial ideas, perhaps as I learn more I may find this approach won't be a good one, but it seems ok to me? I would be interested in any feedback on this 2 cents worth :-)

Cheers

Comment: Wouldn't it best to just ditch the namespaces and create a module called TestModule?

Comment: You should take an AngularJs tutorial before starting AngularJs.